# For loop error looping through rows on macro while extracting data from CSV files and putting selected data in a summary worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am a supply chain analyst trying to summarize daily inventory CSV files on a separate spread sheet. On this spreadsheet, columns are different dates and there is 669 columns. Rows are certain items I want to check the inventory of and there is 3019 rows.

I have a macro with two functions: one opens the csv files and the other gets the values matching the item numbers that are on my spreadsheet. I have found these functions on stack overflow. I loop through the columns/dates with a while loop that runs until there is no more dates. I loop through the rows/items with a for loop that runs from 2 to 3019. There is also an if statement inside the for loop. This checks to see if there is a single inventory data or multiple inventory entries for first and second warehouses. In the latter case sums up the inventory levels of both warehouses for the same items.I also shared the functions that I've used in the for loop.

```
Sub SummaryFile ()
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

c = 2
While Not (IsEmpty(Cells(1, c).Value))

    For r = 2 To 3019
        If fso.fileexists(filepath) Then
            arr = CsvToArray(filepath)
            Cells(r, c).Value = TestLookup(arr, Cells(r, 1), 2, 3)
        ElseIf fso.fileexists(filepath1) And fso.fileexists(filepath2) Then
            arr1 = CsvToArray(filepath1)
            arr2 = CsvToArray(filepath2)
            Cells(r, c).Value = TestLookup(arr1, Cells(r, 1), 2, 3) + TestLookup(arr2, Cells(r, 1), 2, 3)
        End If
    Next r
Wend
End Sub



Function TestLookup(arr, val, lookincol As Integer, returnfromcol As Integer)
Dim r
r = Application.Match(val, Application.Index(arr, 0, lookincol), 0)
If Not IsError(r) Then
    TestLookup = arr(r, returnfromcol)
Else
    TestLookup = Null 'or some other "error" value
End If
End Function


Function CsvToArray(filepath) As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
CsvToArray = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
wb.Close False
End Function
```

I just want to get the inventory numbers for each of the items on each of the dates. If the item is not on the inventory list for that day then the "TestLookup" function returns a Null. When I try it on small number of rows and columns to test it it works, but when I try it for all the dates and items I need it for. It either finishes running the macro after a long time and it had only ran the macro on the first column and none of the other columns are populated or it gives an error saying it ran out of memory. Any ideas?

Comment: Considering that declaration are ok (you are not declaring any variable), in your conditional, if there is a single CSV, you are adding and if there are more, you are copying again. If `fso.fileexists(filepath)` is true it is not against `fso.fileexists(filepath1) And fso.fileexists(filepath2)`, so maybe you are copying twice.

Comment: How many items have you got in your CSV files?

Comment: I had like a 1000 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using python pandas dataframes and merged them (similar to SQL join) so I didn't have use a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with a database like Access or SQL Server to do heavy calculation stuff like that. 
Excel is good to show tables or graphs based on the result of queries providing by such software but is not adapted for processing that amount of data, ie 669 * 3018 = 2019042 iterations.